# WinForms & Entity Framework: Display child entity data in WinForms parent data grid view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, entity-framework-4

Let's say I have these two tables:

**Category**

```
Id int primary key,
Name nvarchar(50) not null,
Description ntext null,
AnotherColumn nvarchar(20) not null,
AndYetAnotherColumn nchar(10) null
```

**Product**

```
Id int primary key,
CategoryId int not null (references Category.Id),
Name nvarchar(20) not null
OtherStuff...
```

I have a `Product` entity that has a navigational `EntityReference` of type `Category`, i.e. one product can belong to only one category but one category may have many products.

Let's say I want to display products in a grid, but I want to also display the `Category.Name` and `Category.AndYetAnotherColumn` in along with the product information in the products data grid.

If I simply bind the `DataGridView` control to the `Products` entity object, it displays a column named `Category` that binds to the `Category` navigational property, and the cells in each row for this column display the `System.Type` of the `Category` class, which happens to be `MyProjectNamespace.Category`.

How do I, without creating and binding with another ViewModel or Repository or some custom class that returns me the hybrid data I need, display this stuff into a data grid? It is a project requirement that I do not create a ViewModel or a middle class.

Comment: you need a middle class to denormalise the data; the data grid will display a single row of data in a single row on the grid. Using an anonymous type as per Devart's solution below is probably the simplest option.

Answer (score 2):

Use the code like the following:

```
Entities db = new Entities();
var q = from it in db.Products
        select new
        {
          it.Id,
          it.Name,
          it.OtherStuff,
          it.Category.Name,
          it.Category. AndYetAnotherColumn
        };
dataGridViewInstance.DataSource = q.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is create a View in your database, and use EntityFramework to mapping as a new entity